# UIManager.setLookAndFeel for nested classes

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to set the look and feel **once** and have it "cascade" to all nested classes?

In the example below, I set the look and feel within the class `Test`, however the `JFileChooser` that I add to my `MainPanel` class (nested within my `Test` class) *does not* have its look and feel adjusted unless I set it *again* within that class.

Is this just something I will need to do for every class I create? Or is there a way for me to have the same look and feel applied across all classes?

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 * Class to demonstrate UIManager.setLookAndFeel issue.
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * Main program.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Test() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        createGUI();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the JFrame and add the main JPanel.
     */
    public void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        frame.add(new MainPanel(800, 600));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * Class for the main panel that will hold all other components.
     */
    class MainPanel extends JPanel {

        private final int width;
        private final int height;

        /**
         * Serialize/save.
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3727866499459986351L;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
        public MainPanel(int w, int h) {
            this.width = w;
            this.height = h;

            // ISSUE the chooser does not have the look and feel of my OS
            // unless I set the look and feel in this constructor
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            this.add(chooser);
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is in this line:

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

The look and feel you are seeing its the CROSS PLATFORM. This is the Java's original - yikes.

Try to change it to:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and I am sure it will be changed.

Comment: I'm actually running on Windows - I am guessing the reason it isn't "cascading" to my components is because `MainPanel` is a seperate class that is extending `JPanel`, instead of just another JPanel object.

Comment: @sleepToken I was wrong. I just noticed. I am editing my question right now.

Comment: Cheers - carelessness on my part with Eclipse auto-complete. Funny enough, I was using `getSystem...` in my nested class, but not my main class /whoops